# Is there a way in Swift to iterate over an encodable struct's property names without an instance of the struct?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reflection

I am aware that you can use `Mirror` to reflect over an instance like so:

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

let person = Person(name: "Joe", age: 21)
let personMirror = Mirror(reflecting: person)

for child in personMirror.children {
     if let label = child.label {
          print(label)
     }
}
```

However, in my case, I don't yet have an instance, but I would want something like this to work:

```
let personTypeMirror = Mirror(reflecting: Person.self)
```

But this has a `children` count of 0.

Comment: Not that I have heard of, reflection in swift is quite limited.

Comment: Check https://forums.swift.org/t/can-mirror-or-other-reflection-work-from-the-type-not-an-instance/47027

Comment: From what I understand, mirror reflect an instance not an instance type.